# Assistance grouping nested html table via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I have an html table with 3 layers of expand/collapse functionality. What I am seeking to achieve is to have the layers actually expand/collapse underneath the parents instead of to the right, basically what they would become is a downward slope once they are expanded. Here is my JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/htfLmekL/1/

```
//expand collapse based on parent class which is column 1
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.parent').prepend('-');

  $('.parent').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).text().indexOf('-') != -1) {
      var str0 = $(this).text().replace(/-/g, '+');
      $(this).text(str0);
    } else {
      var str = $(this).text().replace(/\+/g, '-');
      $(this).text(str);
    }
    var $row = $(this).parent();
    var rowspan = +$(this).attr('rowspan') || 4;
    $.merge($row, $row.nextAll()).slice(0, rowspan).find('.alliance').toggle();
    $.merge($row, $row.nextAll()).slice(0, rowspan).find('.race').toggle();
    $.merge($row, $row.nextAll()).slice(0, rowspan).find('.role').toggle();
    $.merge($row, $row.nextAll()).slice(0, rowspan).find('.resource').toggle();
    $.merge($row, $row.nextAll()).slice(0, rowspan).find('.weapon').toggle();
    $.merge($row, $row.nextAll()).slice(0, rowspan).find('.price').toggle();

  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created something like this ... Though you will have to tweak CSS a lot to get it perfect.  Hope this helps...

```
        <style>
  .tftable {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #333333;
  width: 100%;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #729ea5;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tftable th {
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: #acc8cc;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #729ea5;
  text-align: left;
}

.tftable tr {
  background-color: #d4e3e5;
}

.tftable td {
  font-size: 12px;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #729ea5;

}

.tftable tr:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.race {
    width: 50px;
}


</style>

    </head>
    <body>








        <table class="tftable" border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Group</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><a onclick="javascript:toggleDiv(this,'grp1child1');"> - </a>Group 1

                    <table id="grp1child1" class="tftable" border="1"> 
                        <tr>
                            <th>Alliance : <a onclick="javascript:toggleDiv(this,'grp1child2');"> - </a>Good</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td >
                                <table id="grp1child2" class="tftable" border="1">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="race">Race: </th>
                                        <th><a onclick="javascript:toggleDiv(this,'grp1child3');" > - </a>Humans</th>
                                        <th><a onclick="javascript:toggleDiv(this,'grp1child4');"> - </a>Elves</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <table id="grp1child3" class="tftable" border="1">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th colspan="3">&nbsp;</th>
                                                    <th>Price</th>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                </tr>

                                            </table>

                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <table id="grp1child4" class="tftable" border="1">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th colspan="3">&nbsp;</th>
                                                    <th>Price</th>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                </tr>

                                            </table>                                
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>                                    

                                </table>                                
                            </td>
                        </tr>



                    </table>

                </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <th><a onclick="javascript:toggleDiv(this,'grp2child1');"> - </a>Group 2

                    <table id="grp2child1" class="tftable" border="1"> 
                        <tr>
                            <th >Alliance : <a onclick="javascript:toggleDiv(this,'grp2child2');"> - </a>Evil</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table id="grp2child2" style="width : 100%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="race">Race: </th>
                                        <th><a onclick="javascript:toggleDiv(this,'grp2child3');" > - </a>Trolls</th>
                                        <th><a onclick="javascript:toggleDiv(this,'grp2child4');"> - </a>Ogres</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <table id="grp2child3" class="tftable" border="1">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th colspan="3">&nbsp;</th>
                                                    <th>Price</th>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                </tr>

                                            </table>

                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <table id="grp2child4" class="tftable" border="1">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th colspan="3">&nbsp;</th>
                                                    <th>Price</th>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                </tr>

                                            </table>                                
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>                                    

                                </table>                                
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>

                </th>
            </tr>




        </table>



<script>

function toggleDiv(linkobj,divId) {
    linkobj.innerHTML = (linkobj.innerHTML === ' - ') ? ' + ' : ' - ' ;
    $("#"+divId).toggle();
}


</script>
```

Comment: This is really close to what I am trying to achieve, however how could i get group 2 to actually be under group 1? And basically have all headers removed except the price header?